# HTML entity encoding (convert '<' to '&lt;') on iPhone in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html-encode

I'm developing an application for the iPhone that has inApp-mail sending capabilities. So far so good, but now I want to avoid html-injections as some parts of the mail are user-generated texts.

Basically I search for something like this:

```
// inits
NSString *sourceString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello world! Grüße dich Welt <-- This is in German."];

//                                          -----   THAT'S WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR
// pseudo-code                              |
//                                          V
NSString *htmlEncodedString = [sourceString htmlEncode];

// log
NSLog(@"source string: %@", sourceString);
NSLog(@"encoded string: %@", htmlEncodedString);
```

***Expected output*** 
`source string: Hello world! Grüße dich Welt <-- This is in German.`
`encoded string: Hello world! Gr&#252;&#223;e dich Welt &lt;-- This is in German.`


I already googled and looked through several of SO's questions and answers, but all of them seem to be related to *URL-encoding* and that's not what I really need (I tried `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` with no luck - it creates %C3%BC out of an 'ü' that should be an ü).

A code sample would be really great (correcting mine?)...

--
Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out my [NSString category for HTML](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m). Here are the methods available:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

Comment: To make it work with ARC, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Just add the flag "-fno-objc-arc" to the compile sources of the NSString category.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @all. I ended up using my own implementation:

```
//
// _________________________________________
//
// textToHtml
// _________________________________________
//
- (NSString*)textToHtml:(NSString*)htmlString {
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&"  withString:@"&amp;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"  withString:@"&lt;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"  withString:@"&gt;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"""" withString:@"&quot;"];    
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"  withString:@"&#039;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];
    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: just a side note: since you are also replacing \n with <br> that you should name your function differently (textToHtml for example). The name escapeHTML will indicate to other developers that you are just doing escaping (which you are not) and this will eventually cause bugs if someone tries to re-use this function...

Comment: Good point. Just updated the code snippet accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you leaking a bunch of NSStrings there?

Comment: Wait, no, they're all autoreleased: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531550/string-manipulation-without-memory-leaks

Comment: it's great, but why not just call [self stringByReplacing...] in the first line if it's not a static method? You also won't need to pass in an argument

Answer (score 3):

A little improvement on @Markus' code [Change <br /> to <p></p>, escape multiple spaces]

```
- (NSString*)textToHtml:(NSString*)htmlString {
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&"  withString:@"&amp;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"  withString:@"&lt;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"  withString:@"&gt;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"""" withString:@"&quot;"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"  withString:@"&#039;"];

    htmlString = [@"<p>" stringByAppendingString:htmlString];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"</p>"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"</p><p>"];
//  htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />"];
    while ([htmlString rangeOfString:@"  "].length > 0) {
        htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@"&nbsp;&nbsp;"];
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a similar solution and this did the job for me

```
NSString* value = @"<&>";
const void* keys[1] = {CFSTR("somekey")};
const void* values[1] = {value};    
CFDictionaryRef dicRef =  CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1, nil, nil);    
CFDataRef dataRef = CFPropertyListCreateData(kCFAllocatorDefault, dicRef, kCFPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0, 0, NULL);    
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:(NSData *)dataRef encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSRange start =[str rangeOfString:@"string>"];
NSRange end =[str rangeOfString:@"</string"];    
NSString *substr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location+start.length, end.location-(start.location+start.length))];
[str release];
CFRelease(dicRef);
CFRelease(dataRef);
```

//Substring is now html entity encoded

I am using some of the features that is used when saving plist files. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding @Markus answer, because my case is i'm sending JSON string, so i need to added some escape, these are my function :

note : 
the exception reference from w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

```
- (NSString*)convertStringToHTMLEscape:(NSString*)stringContent
{
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@"%7B"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@"%7D"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@"%5B"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@"%5D"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"%5C"];
    stringContent = [stringContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];

    return stringContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the character encoding of the email supports Unicode - say UTF-8 - could you not just find and replace the occurrences of `<`, `>`, and `&` with `&lt`, `&gt`, and `&amp;`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically you are right, but as there is a function to encode URLs (stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding) I wondered if there is no similar one for HTML character encoding. I'd find it strange if I was the first one with this kind of _problem_ and even stranger if there wasn't a "right" way of doing this that is other than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: No, there's no such built-in function. You could use NSScanner to replace as suggested by teabot; here's an approach that completely strips HTML tags, you could just modify it: http://sugarmaplesoftware.com/25/strip-html-tags/