# Is there a way for NSString to display HTML character codes?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have an NSString that has the following value:

```
   "What#39;s up fellas!"
```

Is there a simple way to turn HTML char codes like `#39;` (equivalent to ') into an apostrophe etc?

Comment: This isn't proper HTML encoding: it's missing an ampersand. The correct HTML encoding would be "What&#39;s up fellas!"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666717/html-entity-encoding-convert-to-lt-on-iphone-in-objective-c

Comment: @Toby, that question is not a dupe, it asks the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check [GTMNSString+HTML.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h) out :) It's a part of the Google Toolbox, an extension for iOS development.
taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html) question

Comment: More explanation in the answer is always useful :)

Comment: @Toby Allen i agree, but i didn't feel it was necessary to simply copy paste stuff from where i linked it as everything is written there, edited the question anyway

Comment: This category looks well-coded and I think should do the trick. Great find!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this one](http://www.dev-smarter.com/nsstring-decode-and-encode-html-character-entities/), it works:

```
#import "NSString+HTML.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *r = @"This is a '\'";
     NSString *s = @"This is a &ltHTML-Tag&gt";

     NSString *encodedstring =  [r kv_encodeHTMLCharacterEntities];

     NSString *decodedstring =  [s kv_decodeHTMLCharacterEntities];

}
```

Comment: Dear Phil, stop using bit.ly every time you post an answer.

Answer (score -2):

NSString has an UTF8 encode-decode function:

```
- (id)initWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes
+ (id)stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes
- (const char *)UTF8String
```

See the [Class Reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: The shown example isn't UTF-8 encoded. These functions won't help.