# NSXMLParser Missing Characters

Tags: objective-c, format, nsxmlparser

I am analyzing an XML file using `NSXMLParser`, which works great but sometimes gives me inaccurate results.

For example, I get this URL:

```
http://www.thehungersite.com/clickToGive/home.faces;jsessionid=01F974DC9E276DA587AE299175EDF4F4.ctgProd02?siteId=4&#38;link=ctg_trs_home_from_ths_home_sitenav
```

but `NSXMLParser` outputs:

> `http://www.thehungersite.com/clickToGive/home.faces;jsessionid=01F974DC9E276DA587AE299175EDF4F4.ctgProd02?siteId=4&link=ctg_trs_home_from_ths_home_sitenav`

For some reason, it ignored the `#38;` part of the string - how can I get this back? Assuming this was HTML encoding I have tried `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` but that will not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the top answer to this question might help:
[Objective-C: How to replace HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797/objective-c-how-to-replace-html-entities?tab=active#tab-top)

It's basically a category to NSString someone made that offers both encoding and decoding of HTML entities in NSString.

Comment: Is there a way to stop NSXMLParser from converting it in the first place?

Comment: The NSXMLParserDelegate has methods for detecting internal entities and external entities, but I'm not sure whether HTML entities will fit under there http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate

Answer (score 1):

XML uses the same character reference encoding mechanism as HTML (although it has only 5 predefined named entities, as opposed to the huge number defined for HTML). `&#38;` is an encoding for the `&` character.

Comment: Yes, `&` is being retained - how do I convert it back?

Comment: @DavidSchieer: See [HTML entity encoding (convert '<' to '&lt;') on iPhone in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666717/html-entity-encoding-convert-to-lt-on-iphone-in-objective-c)

Answer (score -1):

You're using the ISO standard. Try either using %26 or by using url encoding.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812473/difference-between-url-encode-and-html-encode/1812486#1812486 for more on HTML encoding vs. URL encoding. Also, %26 is the encoded text for the '&' when it is urlencoded.

Comment: Thank you - I was aware of this. The problem I am facing is that I cannot convert it back to the original value.