# inserting html string into sqlite db using objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the below snippet to insert html string into sqlite db, my code works fine but when i retrieve the same html string and display in web view it doesn't render, some data is getting modified, can anyone please help how to insert long html strings into db.

> const char *sql = "insert into articles
>   (art_id,sub_cat_id,art_title,art_details) Values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
>
> ```
>                     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
>                         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
>
>                     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"art_id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
>                     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"sub_cat_id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
>                     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[tuser objectForKey:@"art_title"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
>                     sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [[tuser objectForKey:@"art_details"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
>
>
>                     if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
>                         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
>                     else
>                         //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
>                         //coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
>
>                         //Reset the add statement.
>                         sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
> ```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "some data" and its "getting modified"?

Comment: Hi some double quotes and single quotes are getting truncated, thanks deepesh

Comment: It is quite possible that the problem has nothing to do with saving/retrieving the data from sqlite. You may want to provide more info on how the HTML gets handled on its way to and from the database.

Comment: before inserting when i copied the string it was showing up in browser, later when i insert and retrieve it, nothing works, so there is something getting modified, can you help me knowing what is the best process to follow to insert long html string in sqlite db using objective c

Comment: Add logging to see when the changeover happens. If necessary, try retrieving the string from the database immediately after inserting it. Other than a possibility of the ending segment being truncated because of line sizing issues, I see nothing wrong with the code from your post.

Answer (score 3):

The single quotes are likely causing the issue.  Since it's HTML you can replace the single quotes with an & apos; or you can "double" the single quote like shown here so that sqlite is okay with it:

```
    NSString *artdetails = [tuser objectForKey:@"art_details"];
    NSString *arttitle = [tuser objectForKey:@"art_title"];

    NSString *ad = [artdetails stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];    
    NSString *at = [arttitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
```

...

```
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [at UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [ad UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

etc

Comment: on a similar approach, look into encoding your string before writing it to sqlite and then decoding it upon retrieval to ensure special characters don't conflict with insert statement   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666717/html-entity-encoding-convert-to-lt-on-iphone-in-objective-c