# how to store html string in sqlite using objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I want to store an html description tag into a sqlite database. Basically I convert the tag to a string but when I try to insert it into the database i get a near"0": syntax error.
does anyone know of a way I can store the string?

Comment: How are you attempting to insert the string? Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094120/inserting-html-string-into-sqlite-db-using-objective-c (which doesn't have a selected answer, but should help you)

Comment: @powerj1984 sorry, thanks for the link

Comment: No problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use FMDatabase (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a SQLite wrapper for iOS/Cocoa. FMDatabase is a very popular framework, used in endless projects and well maintained. I heavily use it for more than 4 years.

**Code sample**:

```
FMDatabase *db; // Your DB object
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO table (key,value) VALUES (?, ?)", yourKey, longHtmlString, nil];
```