# Html tagged String not acting as String in swift . So I am having problem with inserting them into sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

This is the String from api . but it is not getting stored in the sqlite in the column which is made as TEXT .

```
"<p><b>SPECIFICATION</b><b><br />
    </b><b>General<br />
    </b></p>
    <ul>
     <li>Brand: Abcd</li>
     <li>Model: RT473w58SL</li>
     <li>Color: Silver</li>
     <li>Capacity: 467895 Ltrs</li>
     <li>Door: Double Door Refrigerator</li>
     <li>Defrosting Type: Frost Free</li>
     <li>Compressor Type: Digital Inverter Compressor</li>
    </ul>
    <p><b>Feature<br/></b></p>
    <ul>
     <li>Display and Control (Fridge and Freezer): External</li>
     <li>Smart Connect Inverter (Auto) , Lock and Key</li>
     <li>Fresh Room , Power, Power Cool, Cool Pack 12 hr</li>
     <li>Convertible 5 Modes</li>
     <li>Number of Vegetable and Fruit Drawers (Refrigerator): 2</li>
     <li>Big Guards , Anti Bacteria Protector</li>
     <li>Refrigerator and Freezer or Light: LED</li>
     <li>Freezer Shelf Material: Cool Pack</li>
     <li>Big Bottle Guard , Second Vegetable Box</li>
     <li>Easy Slide Shelf , Convertible Fridge and Freezer</li>
     <li><span class="key-title">Warranty Policy EN: 100 years in Compressor</span>
    <div class="html-content key-value"></div>
    </li>
   </ul>
    "
```

Everything is working ok except the above string which is not getting stored in Sqlite , and when i try to store the above string It doesn't act like string .

Comment: You're going to have to provide a *loooooot* more detail if you want anybody to have any chance of being able to help you. Show code, errors, expected behavior, actual behavior, and everything else you think might help someone answer your question.

Comment: Try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094120/inserting-html-string-into-sqlite-db-using-objective-c?lq=1