# Prevent XSS and Injection in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xss

I read this link that encode HTML tags in IOS
[HTML entity encoding (convert '<' to '&lt;') on iPhone in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666717/html-entity-encoding-convert-to-lt-on-iphone-in-objective-c)
**did this solution usful with XSS** 
And How can I prevent sqlinjection from IOS using  same

if i post data using API and this data insert to database is this make database target to sql injection and XSS

Answer (score 0):

You don't prevent XSS on iOS. You prevent XSS from your application running the web server. For example ASP.NET on IIS or PHP on Apache.

Comment: the date send from ios to database in server

Comment: Are you storing data to a local SQLite database?  Or a remote database via a web services?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing this concept. SQL injection has to be prevented where you access a database using SQL. I guess in your case this will be in the server. Anyway, anywhere you use a SQL database, you should do one of this two things:

- Escape the parameters you have received from any untrusted source (for example, in PHP PDO http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.quote.php)
- Better, use prepared statements that are SQL statements with placeholders for the parameters (i.e. you never mix statements and its parameters) For example, see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: I send comment from my application to database

Comment: Ok. Then you have to prevent SQL injection on your server. iOS app is not involved in the prevention of this.